# Как добавить текст в php?

Tags: url, php

Доброго времени суток.

Есть код, который получается автоматически, это ссылка на картинку. К примеру:

```
<img src="foto.png"/>
```

То есть сам адрес `foto.png` получается автоматически, и  будет `.png` или `.jpg`  адрес, неизвестно.  Так вот  к концу адреса .png  надо добавить `-150x150`, чтобы выглядело так `foto-150x150.png`.

Не подскажите, какой функцией воспользоваться?

Comment: Я ни черта не понял :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$adds = '-150x150';
$path = 'some/path/filename.png';
$pdata = pathinfo($path);

echo $pdata['dirname'].'/'.$pdata['filename'].$adds.'.'.$pdata['extension'];
// some/path/filename-150x150.png
```

Вариант второй:

```
$adds = '-150x150';
$path = 'some/path/filename.png';
$new_path = substr_replace($path, $adds, strrpos($path, '.'),0);
echo $new_path;
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Answer (score 3):

Присоединюсь к празднику торжества безумия

```
function addThumbnailSizing($path)
{
    $chunks = explode('.', $path);
    // предполагается, что путь абсолютно точно валидный
    $chunks[sizeof($chunks) - 2] .= '-150x150';
    return implode('.', $chunks);
}
```

**Обновление**

1. http://tsya.ru
2. http://ideone.com/9NYrhH
3. вообще я очень бурно реагирую на такие предъявы, когда видно, что человек даже не пытался разобраться в том, что я написал.

Comment: К сожалению, в названии тоже может быть точка, к примеру:

     city.filemane.username.jpg

Получится ерунда и совсем неправильный адрес. :)

Comment: То, что вы очень горячий и горделивый человек, видно сразу. То, что ваш код хороший, видно тоже сразу, но он мне не подходит. Почему, я не знаю ни количества точек, кроме последней фразы .jpg, хотя она может быть и .png и .tiff, да и много ещё какой. Не обижайтесь. :) И потом мне не надо было решать через функцию, написаную самому, первое решение куда как элегантнее, как по мне.

Comment: @Sergalas

> То, что ваш код хороший, видно тоже сразу, но он мне не подходит. Почему я не знаю ни количества точек, кроме последней фразы .jpg, хотя она может быть и .png и .tiff, да и много ещё какой.

Именно поэтому там написано решение, которое работает вне зависимости от количества точек и расширений.

Answer (score 1):

Можно завернуть регуляркой.

```
$oldtext = "photo.jpg";
$newtext = preg_replace('/^(.+)(\.)(.+)$/', '$1-150*150$2$3', $oldtext);
echo $newtext; \\ получаем "photo-150*150.jpg"
```

Comment: Нет, регуляркой как раз и не получится, а если ни .jpg, а, скажем, .png или .tiff.

Comment: @Sergalas те же щи, может, стоит проверять код перед его критикой?

http://ideone.com/SFkJbR

Answer (score 0):

Вам это нужно?

```
$size = '150x150';
echo '<img src="foto-'. $size .'.png"/>';
```

Comment: Я так думаю не это ТС нужно. 

Скорее всего дописать размер перед точкой, а именно:

foto.png -> foto-150x150.png